# Not updating object on database ASP.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am having a little issue that I cannot fully comprehend.

On my controller I have:

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutExercise([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Exercise exercise)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Updating item {ID}", id);
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);            

        if (id != exercise.ExerciseId)
            return BadRequest();

        var baseExercise = await repository.GetExercise(id);
        if (baseExercise == null)
            return NotFound(id);

        baseExercise = exercise;
        await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

but it is NOT updating on the database with the values provided on the PUT body request. Although on memory they are changed, the object is not pushed... But if I set a breakpoint on `await unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();` and then modify baseExercise with the debugger, it does update. Why is this happening?

```
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly FitaholicContext context;

    public UnitOfWork(FitaholicContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public Task CompleteAsync()
    { 
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

--

```
public async Task<Exercise> GetExercise(int id, bool includeRelated = false)
    {
        if (!includeRelated)
            return await context.Exercise.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ExerciseId == id);

        return await context.Exercise
                    .Include(e => e.Equipments)
                        .ThenInclude(ee => ee.Equipment)
                    .Include(e => e.TypeRecord)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ExerciseId == id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should using async/await in the function:

```
    public async Task CompleteAsync()
    { 
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but unfortunately it does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the link between the Repository and the UnitOfWork. In order to get the pattern working, and then persist your data, you should only access the repository's methods  ***through***  the unit of work, i.e. the UoW should be just a wrapper for all the repositories related to one database, with the extra purpose of maintaining your data consistency.
In the controller your first retrieve `baseExercise` via `repository.GetExercise(id)`, then you're trying to persist the data with `unitOfWork.CompleteAsync()`. The problem is that you didn't instruct the `uniOfWork` to care about the `repository` behaviour.
That said, it should be a quick fix.
First, set the first part of the link in the `UnitOfWork`:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly FitaholicContext context;

    public UnitOfWork(FitaholicContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    private Repository _repository;
    public Repository repository =>
        this._repository ?? (this._repository =
            new Repository(this.context));

    public Task CompleteAsync()
    { 
        return context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Then the second half, in the `Repository`:

```
public class Repository
{
     public Repository(FitaholicContext context)
     { }

     public async Task<Exercise> GetExercise(int id, bool includeRelated = false)
     { ... }
 }
```

Last step, update `PutExercise()` in the controller to reflect the logic changes:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> PutExercise([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Exercise exercise)
{
    ...

    var baseExercise = await this.unitOfWork.repository.GetExercise(id);

    ...

    await this.unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

If you need to dig a bit deeper into the Repository-UnitOfWork pattern, check the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: Hi, I have upvoted your reply because you did reply good, although it is not the correct solution. 

The problem resides on the fact that I mistakenly assumed I could change the variable baseExercise and UoW would know that I changed the values. But at assigning baseExercise = Exercise I was essentially changing the pointers, declaring a totally new variable instead of modifying the existing one. Therefore, context was not able to keep track of it as baseExercise technically did not change, what we changed was just what it points to. I will answer my own question with more details soon. TY!